Calculation of the volume of a solid of rotation
Calculate the centroid of the homogeneous solid generated by the rotation around the y-axis of the domain in the xy-plane defined by: $$D=\left \{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2 : x \in [1,2],0\leq y \leq \frac{1}{x}\right\}$$I'm calculating only the ordinate of this centroid because all other coordinates will be zero. $$y_G = \frac{\iiint_V y \ dx \ dy \ dz}{(V)}$$I'm applying the Guldinus theorem related to solids of revolution. $$V=2\pi \iint_D x \ dx \ dy \Rightarrow 2\pi \int^2_1 x \ dx \ \int^{\frac{1}{x}}_0 dy \Rightarrow 2\pi \int^2_1 dx \Rightarrow 2\pi$$
I'm doing the numerator in the same way. $$y_G = \frac{2\pi \iint_D xy \ dx \ dy}{2\pi}$$I'm applying the Tonelli-Fubini reduction formula $$\int^2_1 x \ dx \ \int^{\frac{1}{x}}_0 y \ dy \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} \int^2_1 x \ [y^2]^{\frac{1}{x}}_0 \ dx \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} \int^2_1 \frac{dx}{x} = \frac{1}{2} \log|x| \Bigg|^2_1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\log2$$
My questions are:

Was the exercise performed correctly?
Are there other ways to do this exercise?

